# Bearer Token on HTTP Request

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-studio

I try to replace the token with a variable so that i dont need to hardcode the token but it seems I cant do it.[image: Token on HTTP Request]
and this is the output from postman
`"You called the function '+' with these arguments:
1: String ("Bearer ")
2: String ("eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImprdSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vcHQtZGVtby1jZi1ldTEwLXNieC5hdXRoZW50...)

But it expects one of these combinations:
(Array, Any)
(Date, Period)
(DateTime, Period)
(LocalDateTime, Period)
(LocalTime, Period)
(Number, Number)
(Period, DateTime)
(Period, LocalDateTime)
(Period, Time)
(Period, Date)
(Period, LocalTime)
(Time, Period)

### 4| "Authorization" : 'Bearer ' + payload.message,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Trace:
at anonymous::main (line: 4, column: 19)" evaluating expression: "output application/java

{
"Authorization" : 'Bearer ' + payload.message,
"x-qos" : "1"
}".
`

I expect it will wokr just fines since if i hardcode the token. The flow will work just fine.

Comment: That doesn't look like Java.

Comment: You concatenate using `++` and not `+` in Dataweave. Refer this for basics of Dataweave https://developer.mulesoft.com/tutorials-and-howtos/dataweave/what-is-dataweave-getting-started-tutorial/

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. Also use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for code, errors and logs.

Comment: @tgdavies it looks like DataWeave, the expression language in Mule 4.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are new to MuleSoft and DataWeave. As the error message indicates, you cannot use the "+" operator for string concatenation. To concatenate two or more strings, one option is to use the ++ function. Another more advanced technique is to use the $() syntax. You can read more about these methods [here](https://developer.mulesoft.com/tutorials-and-howtos/concatenation-dataweave-functions-tips-and-tricks/)

Example:

Using **++** for concatenation

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "Authorization": "Bearer " ++ payload.message
}
```

Using **$()** for concatenation

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "Authorization": "Bearer $(payload.message)"
}
```

Comment: You should separate both examples to avoid confusions.